# Google Analytics vs Adobe Analytics

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, analytics, adobe-analytics

I went through google analytics and adobe analytics for the mobile app. I see that you can track who your users are, retention rate, how much time users are spending, attribution tracking, customer parameter tracking, referral tracking.

Google Analytics dashboard generates all these reports real time. Same adobe analytics does. GA has more advantage in terms of cost as it is free for small companies product, implementation is also easy and dashboard is quite easy to use.

Where adobe analytics to use ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: **Use Adobe when you want a more advanced and customizable analytics tool and when the complexity of it isn't an issue.**

Slightly longer answer: Adobe analytics is extremely customizable and there are options to add enhanced conversion tracking. Basically you can track whatever you want, exactly the way you want it tracked.

Pros/Features that are more advanced in Adobe analytics:

- path reports & PathFinder
- flexible segmentation within the reporting tool
- predictive insights
- ability to visualize your entire conversion funnel

I would personally start with using Google analytics and if it is insufficient for the project I would look into Adobe analytics, especially in a large company with large requirements. Though, there are situations where it makes more sense to use Google analytics like in an e-commerce site.

Comment: what do you mean by more advance and customizable analytics ?

Comment: @AjayS See the [feature section](https://business.adobe.com/products/analytics/adobe-analytics-features.html) on their website. Some of these exist in GA but they are generally more advanced in Adobe analytics and it is definitely possible to customize it to your exact use case.